# Como salvar as medias obtidas em um dataframe, em uma nova coluna contendo as médias desse dataframe usando pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Boa noite,
Estou com um problema de tentar salvar valores da média de uma df, em uma unica coluna.
Um exemplo de como eu queria que ficasse era:

Dataframe

[image]

[image]

Nessa primeira parte, apenas abri meu dataframe e transpuz para obter com a função mean() os valores das médias.

[image]

Talvez seja uma dúvida meio besta, mas realmente não estou conseguindo colocar os valores das medias que obtive naquela função mean() em uma nova coluna com tais valores. Tem jeito de fazer isso? Desde já, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para colocar a média na última coluna, é necessário:

1. Transformar a primeira linha em cabeçalho
2. Efetuar o cálculo da média no eixo vertical (`axis=0`)
3. Indicar que você quer o cálculo (da média) apenas com os valores numéricos, caso contrário, os labels (ex: 'consumo1') irão interferir no cálculo.

Segue abaixo como efetuar a inserção da coluna 'media':

```
# Cria o DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'cliente':[1,2,3],'consumo1':[10,11,45],'consumo2':[12,20,10],'consumo3':[13,45,18]})

# Transpõe
df_transp = df.T

# Saída
df_transp
           0   1   2
cliente    1   2   3
consumo1  10  11  45
consumo2  12  20  10
consumo3  13  45  18

# Seta o nome das colunas para os valores da primeira linha
df_transp.columns = df_transp.iloc[0]

# Define os dados começando a partir da segunda linha
df_transp = df_transp[1:]

# Saída
df_transp
cliente    1   2   3
consumo1  10  11  45
consumo2  12  20  10
consumo3  13  45  18

# AQUI => Cria a coluna 'media' com os valores 
# da média (apenas para valores numéricos) calculados 
# no eixo vertical (axis=0)
df_transp.loc[:,'media'] = df_transp.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=0).values

# Saída
df_transp
cliente    1   2   3      media
consumo1  10  11  45  11.666667
consumo2  12  20  10  25.333333
consumo3  13  45  18  24.333333
```

Comment: Conseguiu sanar minhas dúvidas, e ainda consegui aplicar em outras situações, obrigado!!